# How does ng-bind extract the $scope child from the attr value passed to it?

Tags: angularjs-directive, ng-bind

I'm trying to make a custom ng-directive that gets `$scope.object.variable` by the value passed to it as an $attribute - "object.variable"  (just like ng-bind does)

```
<my-directive shows="object.variable">
```

I couldn't understand how [ng-bind does it by looking at its source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js), but that is exactly what I want.

([it uses *`.ngBind`?*](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L57) doesn't work for me, gives me undefined) How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source ngBind works by setting up a $watch based on the value of ng-bind attribute.

```
  scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
    // We are purposefully using == here rather than === because we want to
    // catch when value is "null or undefined"
    // jshint -W041
    element.text(value == undefined ? '' : value);
  });
```

When the value is undefined (which it will be if the binding expression was never initialized), then it will replace the contents of the element with empty text.

Comment: `attr.ngBind` gives me undefined. always. I've made sure that `attr` or whatever I pass to `.ngBind` has a value which corresponds to a child object in my `$scope`, but it still always gives me undefined. What *is* `.ngBind`? How does it extract the value from $scope?

Comment: ah f@#$! it's `ng-bind`, the name of the attribute itself!! I should be passing `attr.show` instead.